# React Native token issue when submit

Tags: react-native

i build an application with reactNative and Expo for front-end and django for back-end

i want take token from AsyncStorage to recognised the user, but the is an errors
Warning: An unhandled error was caught from submitForm(), [ReferenceError: Can't find variable: useState]

when i change the owner id to static value the submit works fine and show the token value on the console log not sure where is the issue exactly

```
import React, {useState} from 'react';
import { FieldArray, Formik } from "formik";
import axios from "axios";
import AsyncStorage from '@react-native-async-storage/async-storage';
import jwt_decode from "jwt-decode";


function AddScreen(props){
  const submit = ({ type, category, amount }) => {

     //here you define the token to be set
  const [token, setToken] = useState();
  //here you get the token from AsyncStorage
  const getToken = async () => {
    try {
      const data = await AsyncStorage.getItem('token');
      if (data !== null) {
        setToken(data)
        return data;
      }
    } catch (error) {
      console.log(error);
    }
  };
  //here you set the token
  getToken()
  //here you decode the token
  const tokens = token;
  const decoded = jwtDecode(tokens);
  //here you get the id and it returns a number
  const id = decoded.user_id

    const config = {
      headers: {
        "Content-Type": "application/json",
      },
    };
    const date = Date.now();
    const owner = id;
    const body = JSON.stringify({ type, category, amount, date, owner });
    if (type == "" || category == "" || amount == "") {
      alert("Please Enter all details");
      return;
    }
    // 'http://192.168.8.143:8000/transactions/'
    axios
      .post("http://192.168.8.143:8000/transactions/", body, config)
      .then(function (response) {
        console.log(response);
      })
      .catch(function (error) {
        console.log(error);
      });
  };

  return (
    <View style={{ flex: 1, backgroundColor: COLORS.gray }}>
      <Formik
        initialValues={{ type: "", category: "", amount: "" }}
        onSubmit={(values) => {
          submit(values);
        }}
      >
        {(props) => (
          <View style={styles.whitecard}>
            <TextInput
              style={styles.inputstyle}
              placeholder="type"
              onChangeText={props.handleChange("type")}
              value={props.values.type}
            />

            <TextInput
              style={styles.inputstyle}
              placeholder="category"
              onChangeText={props.handleChange("category")}
              value={props.values.category}
            />
            <TextInput
              style={styles.inputstyle}
              placeholder="amount"
              onChangeText={props.handleChange("amount")}
              value={props.values.amount}
              keyboardType="numeric"
            />

            <View
              style={{
                margin: 10,
                padding: 0,
                backgroundColor: COLORS.pink,
                borderRadius: 6,
              }}
            >
              <Button
                title="Submit"
                color="white"
                onPress={props.handleSubmit}
              ></Button>
            </View>
          </View>
        )}
      </Formik>
    </View>
  );
};

...

export default AddScreen;
```

the error show

Warning: An unhandled error was caught from submitForm(), [Error: Invalid hook call. Hooks can only be called inside of the body of a function component. This could happen for one of the following reasons:

1. You might have mismatching versions of React and the renderer (such as React DOM)
2. You might be breaking the Rules of Hooks
3. You might have more than one copy of React in the same app
   See https://reactjs.org/link/invalid-hook-call for tips about how to debug and fix this problem.]

Answer (score 1):

You are not importing UseState from React. Also you need to convert your code into a react functional component.

**EDIT**

For your new error, you need to move the useState out of submit. It must be at the root level of the functional component. I am updating the code example below as well.

```
import React, {useState} from 'react';
//All your other imports
function AddScreen(props) {
  const [token, setToken] = useState(null);
//Everything else remains same inside
};
```

Comment: Thank you, I miss that , but the error still appears

Comment: Can't find variable UseState error?

Comment: i'm not sure, but when i use the owner on static value that work very well

Comment: clear gradle and run app again. If any error is still occuring pls share that error

Comment: i did but still the error show , i update the question share the error

Comment: You need to update the code as well

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/242812/discussion-between-wafa-a-and-tahaf10).